# Excel formular multiple sheets between dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am struggling with a formular in excel to show the totals of rows across multiple sheets based on dates. Here is an example

Sheet 1

No of Days: Today - 2

```
Name  ¦  Total

Abc   ¦  6

Def   ¦  8
```

Sheet 2

```
Name ¦ 15/03/2024 ¦ 16/03/2024 ¦ 17/03/2024

Abc  ¦    7       ¦    3       ¦    8

Def  ¦    4       ¦    1       ¦    2
```

Sheet 3 - 53 (With the date increasing by 1 day at a time, 7 days on each sheet)

```
Name ¦ 18/03/2024 ¦ 19/03/2024 ¦ 20/03/2024

Abc  ¦    1       ¦    2       ¦    3

Def  ¦    5       ¦    0       ¦    3
```

So I basically need the sum of all sheets where the date is less than Today – 2

I hope that makes sense.

I cant see a way of filtering the results by date

Comment: Should not the total be `6` for `Abc` and `8` for `Def`? (`Today` being the 20th and `Today - 2` being the 18th)

Comment: sorry yes you are correct, I will edit

Comment: Less than today minus 2 is less than 18th equals `0` for both. Do you mean the sum of today up to 2 days back (smaller than or equal to today and larger than *(and equal to?)* today minus 2 days?) also your sample shows 1 sheet of 4 columns, while the point is the use of multiple sheets and a date range to be included/excluded. Should you not adapt your samples to your problem?

Comment: Sample updated, I need the Sum across the sheets for the date range. for example today - 2 would give me the Sum of 18/03/2024 , 19/03/2024 & 20/03/2024

Comment: Is there a compelling reason that you need to put those data in separate sheets?

Comment: Just for ease of use really, if I cant do it across multiple sheets I will have to add them all to one

Comment: I see. If you data is in one sheet, filtering columns by date is really easy. but if your data is in multiple sheets, then this problem just becomes much more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `FILTER` and `BYROW` if you are open to put your data in one sheet:

Assuming below data is in range `A1:G3`:

| Name | 15/3/2024 | 16/3/2024 | 17/3/2024 | 18/3/2024 | 19/3/2024 | 20/3/2024 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Abc | 7 | 3 | 8 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| Def | 4 | 1 | 2 | 5 | 0 | 3 |

Below formula should give you the desired results:

```
=BYROW(FILTER(B2:G3,(B1:G1>=DATE(2024,3,18))*(B1:G1<=DATE(2024,3,20)),""),LAMBDA(x,SUM(x)))
```

Here is the formula break down:

1. `FILTER()` filters out columns with Date >= 2024-03-18, and <= 2024-03-20.

```
=FILTER(B2:G3,(B1:G1>=DATE(2024,3,18))*(B1:G1<=DATE(2024,3,20)),"")
```

2.`BYROW()` sums the filtered out columns by row.

```
=BYROW(filteredData,LAMBDA(x,SUM(x)))
```

If it is absolutely necessary to keep your data in separate sheets, you can consider using `INDIRECT` and `HSTACK` to consolidate you data in separate sheets into one table, like below:

```
=HSTACK(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A1:G3"), INDIRECT("Sheet2!A1:G3"))
```

**Alternatively,**

If your columns are always arranged from the earliest date to the latest date, you don't even need `FILTER`, you can just use `TAKE` to get the last three columns and sum them by row:

```
=BYROW(TAKE(B2:G3,,-3),LAMBDA(x, SUM(x)))
```